# Why does my motorcycle's brake get loose easily?

Tags: motorcycle, brakes

I drive a 100cc motorcycle which has *drum brakes* on both the wheels. I have faced this problem with the rear wheel's brake for the past two years and I adjusted it many times.

About an year back, I replaced the rear wheel's drum brake for the first time in 5 years, since the motorcycle was purchased. Even after replacement the same problem occurs and brakes go loose easily.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with motorcycle brakes.  Do the brakes have an auto adjuster like on cars?  Might this not be working properly?  When you say you adjusted, did you adjust the cable, or something inside the brakes?  Were the shoes evenly worn  when you replaced them?

Comment: No, there is no auto adjuster for the brakes. When the problem started initially, I tighened the cable adjuster. Yes, the shoes were evenly worn, they became very thin

Comment: Can you state our make/model/year?

Comment: Make: BAJAJ (www.bajajauto.com) /  Model: CT100 / Year: 2007

Comment: You said the the brake goes 'loose'.  What do you mean by that?  Is it that you get lots of play in the pedal quickly as if the pads are wearing down in an accelerated fashion?

Comment: Day by day, I noticed the brake pedal going lower than the position and some day it literally goes too low , like its gonna touch the floor. @DucatiKiller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drum brakes have the tendency of getting loose every couple of months since unlike disc brakes you will need to apply a lot of force to have proper deceleration and this causes the line to get lose.

Even Disc brake lines get loose but the interval is much much greater than drum brakes.

If your break gets loose say every hundred kilometres then yo will have to change the brake line and things should be back to normal.

Also , I am surprised you changed brakes only one time in 5 years!